# Create a reference to a gameobject based on a raycast hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a reference to an instance of a game object based on if a raycast hits a specific game object. In this case, its called "resource". Once I have click the gameobject I want to create an object of type ResourceSource that holds all variables and methods of that specific gameObject.

E.g i click the gameobject. A varaible is created

```
ResourceSource resource =  hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ResourceSource>();
```

Obviously, I cant just create a new object as that will just be a copy so if I make any changes to the gameobject the original won't be affected.

**ResourceSource class**

```
public class ResourceSource : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ResourceType type;
    public int quantity;
    public UnityEvent onQuantityChange;
    Cooldown cooldown;


    public Vector3 GetPositon()
    {
        return gameObject.transform.position;
    }

}
```

**The method i want to create the reference**

```
 void CheckIfResource(RaycastHit hit)
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Resource")
        {
            //Want to create something like this
            ResourceSource resourcePosition = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ResourceSource>();
        }
    }
```

Still somewhat new to unity so any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

```
ResourceSource resource;
resource = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ResourceSource>();
```

Comment: That's just a longer way to write what you already had ... `ResourceSource resource =  hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ResourceSource>();` behaves exactly the same ... You just separated the definition and declaration of the variable .. which is ok but unnecessary